# MongoDB: Using pipeline in $lookup aggregation returns no data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Good day!

I have accounts which look like this:

```
{ "_id" : '63fdc0172cdd7833d01412fb', "item": "Account Name", "groupId": "VtofkqYIzcNR9NqwP7KB7Fuyuiw2" }
```

and I have utility data that looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : '63fddf12945fg45677bq412', "accountId": '63fdc0172cdd7833d01412fb' }
```

I am trying to perform a MongoDB aggregation on the accounts to return the account and the respective utility data using a $lookup operation. The $lookup returns an empty array however. The aggregation looks like this:

```
[{
    $match: {
        applicationId: 'groupId'
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'utilityData',
        'let': {
            accountId: '$_id'
        },
        pipeline: [{
            $match: {"accountId": "$$accountId"}
        }],
        as: 'data'
    }
}]
```

I suspect it has to do with the let variable assignment as if I hard code the accountId it works.

Please let me know if I there is any error this or if I am performing the aggregation incorrectly.

Thank you!

P.S I attempted this using both Mongoose and MongoDB Compass

Comment: I guess `$match.applicationId` should assigned with `accountId` cause `$match.applicationId` as join key should equals to the field `groupId` in utilityData but your utilityData not contains such a field named as `groupId`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare transformed field(s) between 2 collection, you need to use `$expr` operator.

> `$expr` can build query expressions that compare **fields from the same document** in a `$match` stage.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#behavior

```
db.accounts.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      groupId: "VtofkqYIzcNR9NqwP7KB7Fuyuiw2"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "utilityData",
      "let": {
        accountId: {
          "$toString": "$_id"
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$accountId",
                "$$accountId"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "data"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_2ePfDn84nA)

**Note:** I guess your accounts `_id` field is an `ObjectId`. In that case, we need to apply `$toString` operator to compare `accounts._id`(String) with `utilityData.accountId`(String).